# Gpu util is 0 when run tensorflow training job, and context switch is very high

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

```
tensorflow: 1.2.0
gpu: TITAN X (Pascal)
driver: 370.28
```

I run distrubuted tensorflow to train image classify model, but see no gpu usage(actually,gpu util of mnist or other training job are also 0).

there's many poll system call when straced the training process(poll fd is /dev/nvidia0):

```
 poll([{fd=8, events=POLLIN}, {fd=12, events=POLLIN}, {fd=13, events=POLLIN}, {fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=15, events=POLLIN}, {fd=17, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}, {fd=20, events=POLLIN}, {fd=21, events=POLLIN}], 10, 100 <unfinished ...>
 futex(0x2d1eca4, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE|FUTEX_CLOCK_REALTIME, 3340677, {1502763800, 428734182}, ffffffff) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
```

vmstat shows very high context switch, millions cs per second.

Had someone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem before, but it's because my gpu is not set to run -- I ran tensorflow on my CPU, but I thought it was run on GPU. If you do everything right, it won't be like this.

1) You could check this by use nvidia-smi to check: Despite that the gpu util is 0%, is the gpu memory util also 0% ? If there isn't any process in Processes at all?

-- If so, your gpu is not used at all, the tensorflow must be running on CPU (you may use top to check cpu usage, if it is above 100% then it's an additional proof that the program is actually paraleled on CPU)

In this case, you should check if you've installed the gpu version of tensorflow. You may find 2 different versions of installation introduction in  www.tensorflow.org for cpu/gpu respectly. A CPU version tensorflow may never be run on GPU.

Plus above, some machine enviroment requires you to specify the gpu device you want to use explicitly. Use the command like the following to check:

CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python rnn_mnist.py

(Note =? must be in the right format, e.g. CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=[0] is invalid but no WARNING will be promoted, the program will just run on CPU instead)

2) If it is not the case, that the python is really running on GPU and it's just the util is 0%. There's another possibility that the data fetching cost too much time, which is on CPU, and GPU is always waiting for data, so the util is avg 0%.

-- The most possible reason is that you set batch_size too small, try 128 or 1024.